# How to enable Multiviews in Ubuntu 12.10

Tags: 12.10, apache2, php

https://help.ubuntu.com/12.10/serverguide/httpd.html

It said that:

> Multiview - Support content-negotiated multiviews; this option is
>   disabled by default for security reasons.

How to enable it?

Answer (score 2):

The full quote is:

> Multiview - Support content-negotiated multiviews; this option is disabled by  default for security reasons. See the [Apache2 documentation on this option](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_negotiation.html#multiviews).

After following the link and also have a look at the [option statement](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#options) it should become clear that you can use something like the following example in your apache or virtual host configuration.

```
<Directory /web/docs>
 Options +MultiViews
</Directory>
```